# what is the difference between "grit your teeth" & "grind your teeth"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

what is the difference between "grit your teeth" & "grind your teeth"?

> [grind](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/grind_1?q=grind) ​[intransitive, transitive] to rub together, or to make
>   hard objects rub together, often producing an unpleasant noise
>
> **grind (together)** Parts of the machine were grinding together noisily.
>
> **grind something (together)** She grinds her teeth when she is asleep.
>
> He ground the gears on the car.

---

**[grit your teeth](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/grit_2)**

> ​to bite your teeth tightly together
>
> She gritted her teeth against the pain.
>
> ‘Stop it!’ he said through gritted teeth.

Does "**grind the teeth**" mean the upper & lower teeth touch together & they move backwards & forwards?

& "**grit the teeth**" means the upper & lower teeth touch a little firmly  together?

Comment: You can *grind your teeth* in your sleep, but you can't *grit your teeth* in your sleep. *Gritting your teeth* implies conscious intention, something that can't be done if you're not aware of what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there is no *major* difference between them. Not just *grind* and *grit* your teeth, there are a few more words used for the same; say - *[gnash your teeth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gnash-your-teeth?topic=squeezing-and-grinding),* or even *clench your teeth.* They all express *anger.*

Note that when you aren't angry, it could be a medical condition named [*Bruxism.*](https://kidshealth.org/en/parents/bruxism.html)

Comment: No, _grit your teeth_ expresses resolution or endurance, as explained by Weather Vane.

Comment: @KateBunting the OP was concerned about *figurative use* i.e. an expression made by an angry person. And, I stated that in my answer. IMO, they are **still** the same! ;)

Comment: No, the OP didn't mention anger. The two expressions are used figuratively to refer to _different_ emotions.

Comment: @KateBunting I can think of *three* variations: **grit** when faced with hardship, **clench** when angry but silent, **grind** when suffering anguish.

Comment: @MaulikV OP doesn't mention *figurative*. The question asks about the **physical** movement of the teeth.

Comment: @WeatherVane if it's *physical* movement, it's for sure, the same!

Answer (score 1):

Although some dictionaries state that the phrases "grit your teeth" and "grind your teeth" both mean to be angry or suffer pain, my understanding is there is a difference. The first is a matter of **resolve** and the second a matter of **experience**.

[The Free Dictionary by Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grit+your+teeth) has

> **grit your teeth**
>
> COMMON If you grit your teeth, you continue to do something or accept a situation even if it is difficult or unpleasant.
>
> *There is going to be hardship, but we have to grit our teeth and get on with it. There were five games in nine days, but the players gritted their teeth and kept going.*

Whereas the [same dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grind+your+teeth) has

> **grind your teeth**
>
> If someone grinds their teeth, they are angry about something, but do not express their anger.
>
> *We journalists, who once were just like him, grind our teeth as we contemplate his success.*

So if I have to do a difficult job that I detest I will **grit my teeth** and get on with it. My teeth will be firmly clenched together.

If I am having a nightmare I might literally **grind my teeth** in anguish (I know someone who does this). My lower jaw will be moving from side to side, and the teeth rubbing against each other, sometimes noisily.

But usually, the expressions are figurative.